# Structured Streaming - what is one time trigger?

Tags: python, spark-structured-streaming

We are trying to use the Structured Streaming with Kafka integration for one of the use case. While i was going through the Batch interval, i can see one-time trigger.

Is it same like Daily once (batch processing)?

Based on what it will `trigger the next pull` OR do we need to `schedule` it?

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is right, there's no mechanism on scheduling next batch for one time trigger. So you may need to schedule it manually, something like crontab.

Comment: Since its a streaming, do i need to set the trigger interval as 24 hours, so it can run once per day? what is the equivalent to batch interval in Structured streaming?

Comment: One time trigger is a special kind of trigger which actually doesn't make sense in streaming but the nature of Spark streaming, "micro-batch". A batch will run for each one-time trigger. Please refer below link for more details.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers